# Comparing samples across time periods

Tags: r, t-test

I have about 80,000 observations that I collect each day, which include a numeric variable called amount (it's a bid). I often stuff with determining whether a decrease or increase in the amount, be it by hour, day, or week, is meaningful enough that it warrants further analysis. So let's say I have a week's worth of data and I notice that Thursday had a lower average bid amount than the other days of that week. I want to use a 'test' to determine if the values from Thursday are 'significantly' different from the rest of the week. My initial thought was to use a one-sample t-test as it allows me to assess difference between a sample mean (Thurs's mean bid amount) and the population mean (weekly bid amount) to verify if the null hypothesis is correct.

However, I'm a little confused how to proceed given that I'm dealing with time series data. How then can I go about comparing bid amounts from different time slots or days to determine whether there is a significant increase or decrease in the bid amount?

PS: Question tagged as 'R' because I'll be using R, although the question itself isn't R specific.

Comment: You are correct that using time series data would need to be taken into account, but that is not your main problem. You looked at the data and want to establish whether the highest mean is significantly different. That's a hypothesis suggested by the data. You'd be better off with a model with day of week as a control and testing parameter differences systematically.